# Getting randomly latitude/longitude data in R

Tags: r, google-maps, random, numbers, geocoding

I simulated a dataset for an online Retail market. The customer can purchase their products in different stores in Germany (e.g. Munich, Berlin, Hamburg..) and in Online stores. To get the latitude/longitude data from the cities I use `geocode` from the `ggmap package`. But customers who purchase Online are able to purchase them all over the country. Now I want to generate random latitude/longitude data within Germany for the online purchases, to map them later with shiny leaflet. Is there any way to do this?

My df looks like this:

```
View(df)
ClientId   Store ... lat   lon
1          Berlin    52    13
2          Munich    48    11
3          Online    x     x  
4          Online    x     x
```

But my aim is a data frame for example like this:

```
ClientId   Store ... lat   lon
1          Berlin    52    13
2          Munich    48    11
3          Online    50    12
4          Online    46    10
```

Is there any way to get these random latitude/longitude data and integrate it to my data frame?

Comment: Do you care if the points are actually in Germany? You can get the range of lat/lon that fits a box around the country and use `sample` to get random values in that range. Or you can write a function and have it return random lat/lon in a circle radius around your known areas (ie. 100km from Munich)

Comment: Thank you for the answer! It would be very helpful if there are in Germany. Because the retailer settled in Germany. I had a similar idea like you, but I  have no idea how to code this in R (Im a newbie). And if I am able to generate this random numbers, how can I let R now that these numbers contains to the Online store?

Comment: http://www.dpi.inpe.br/gilberto/tutorials/software/R-contrib/sp/html/spsample.html

Comment: posting this for future SOers who are looking for random geo points from shapefiles/WKT/geojson (since this will be high in the search results for them) https://github.com/ropensci/randgeo does random selection for those.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is twofold. First of all, as a newbie to R, you are not yet used to the semantics required to do what you need. Fundamentally, what you are asking to to do is:

- **First**, Identify which orders are sourced from Online
- **Second**, generate a random lat and lon for these orders

First, to identify elements of your data frame which fit a criterion, you use the `which` function. Thus, to find the rows in your data frame **which** have the Store column equal to "Online", you do:

```
df[which(df$Store=="Online")]
```

To update the lat or lon for a particular row, we need to be able to access the column. To get values of a particular column, we use `$`. For example, to get the lat values for the online orders you use:

```
df$lat[which(df$Store=="Online")]
```

Great! The problem now diverges and increases in complexity. For the new values, do you want to generate simple values to accomplish your demo, or do you want to come up with new logic to generate spacial results in a given region? You indicate you would like to generate data points in Germany itself, however, to accomplish that is beyond the scope of this question. For now, we will consider the easy example of generating values in a bounded box and updating your `data.frame` accordingly.

To generate integer values in a given range, we can use the `sample` function. Assuming that you would want `lat` values in the range of 45 and 55 and `lon` values in the range of 9 to 14 we can do the following:

```
df$lat[which(df$Store=="Online")]<-sample(45:55,length(which(df$Store=="Online")))
df$lon[which(df$Store=="Online")]<-sample(9:14,length(which(df$Store=="Online")))
```

Reading this code, we have update the `lat` values in `df` that are "Online" orders with a vector of random numbers from 48:52 that is the proper length (the number of "Online" orders).

If you wanted more decimal precision, you can use similar logic with the `runif` function which samples from the uniform distribution and `round` to get the appropriate amount of precision. Good luck!